# How do I get HTML pages sent to client side

Tags: php, apache

I am doing some project related to web-crawlers. One important thing is to extract URLs in HTML pages (After PHP has been run) sent to each user. As the web pages may be dynamic, each user may receive different HTML pages. I am just wondering if there is an easy way to extract these pages(actually these URLs) at the server side before they are actually sent out. I know technically as the server I should be able to know exactly the page I am about to send to my user. I just do not know how to do this. Any ideas? I am running PHP+MySQL on Apache Server. Thanks!

To be more specific, I simply wanted to keep a copy of the HTMLs sent to the users so I can extract the URLs in the HTML pages myself for analysis. I wish to do this on fly because HTMLs sent to the users are dynamic so I cannot statically store all the pages.

Forget about the whole crawler story it is actually not quite related to this question.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question I think.  Could you please elaborate on "extract these pages"?

Comment: I just modify the question a little so the question may be clearer to you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating the pages with PHP yourself, you can create a function/method for generating **and** capturing the links, e.g.

```
class Links {
  private static $links = array();

  public static function getLinks () { 
    return self::$links;
  }
  public static function generateLink ($url, $title) {
    // note: you probably want to use htmlspecialchars() for $title
    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
    self::$links[] = $link; 
    return $link;
  }
}

// now generate some links
...
echo Links::generateLink("http://example.com", "example.com");
echo Links::generateLink("http://domain.com/user-specific-link-goes-here", "whatever");
...
```

At the end of the script you can retrieve the generated links via `Links::getLinks()` and store them somewhere:

```
var_dump(Links::getLinks());
```

If you can't change the code that's generating the links, an alternative is to turn on output buffering, generate the HTML code as usual, and at the end of the script try to find all links in the output buffer:

```
ob_start();

// generate HTML as usual
// ...

// at end of script, capture the generated output and capture links in it
$html = ob_get_clean();
preg_match_all("/<a\s+.*?href=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?>.*?<\/a>/i", $html, $matches);
// captured links are now contained in $matches
var_dump($matches);

// send output buffer to client
echo $html;
```

Note that in the second code example it might be necessary to adjust the regular expression so it actually matches the hyperlinks your code generates. Note also that this a *brute-force* method, and will not be accurrate in case of malformed HTML (invalid tag nesting), not take into account HTML comments (e.g. it will find `<-- <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a> -->`) etc.

Comment: Thanks! that is pretty helpful